# Can a codenameone application receive share intents?

Tags: android-intent, codenameone

I've been working and reading through the documentation, and the API docs, but so far I haven't been able to find anything related to receiving intents or sharing something towards a codenameone app.

Is this possible at all? Or are the apps purely working on their own, regardless of their surroundings?

Answer (score 0):

Intents can be invoked through the `Display` class which allows them to return a value.

However, the ability to respond to an intent and embed a foreign activity is very Android specific and has no equivalent parallel on other platforms. You can create such cases by using the native interfaces support built into Codename One (with build arguments for adding entries to the manifest), this also allows for other Android specific concepts such as widgets. However, all such code is obviously Android specific and will only appear when the Android version is built.